# CSS path() function

Tags: css

I recently read something about writing SVG animations in both SMIL and CSS. In that article, the `path()` function of CSS came forward, but I can not find any documentation on this. Any articles and/or documentation on this?

**Example**

```
.stackoverflow-example {
    d: path("<svg commands here>")
}
```

**Edit**

I found an article back from 2015, when this feature just came out (Chrome 46), but there still doesn't seem to be *any* documentation. https://css-tricks.com/smil-is-dead-long-live-smil-a-guide-to-alternatives-to-smil-features/. The paragraph in question can be found under *An alternative: CSS*.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not confusing it with the `svg` `path` function?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure there is no `path()` function in CSS. Could you be meaning the `clip-path` property?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: @JacobGray SVG CSS might have.

Comment: @Hackerman It works in Chrome, Chrome for Android and Opera.

Comment: @JacobGray The example I posted results in a validly drawn svg element. So yes, I exactly mean ```path()```.

Comment: @DevNebulae could you post the link to the tutorial/post that contained `path()`. I can find nothing about path in the MDN docs _or_ the CSS specs, which is slightly worrying...

Comment: @JacobGray That's exactly the point I am facing, I read *something* *somewhere* and now I can't find it anymore.

Comment: @JacobGray Found it after reading carefully. I edited the question with the link to the article and it is found under _An alternative: CSS_.

Comment: @DevNebulae I updated my answer with much more details, you might find it more useful now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR: Don't use `path()` for anything that you want to actually work.

This is the first I've ever heard of `path()` and there's a reason: **It's experimental.**

[`path()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/motion-1/#funcdef-path) is a function specified in [Motion Path Module Level 1 Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/motion-1/). Chrome users can see a [demo here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/css-motion-path/index.html).

The module adds these properties:

- [`motion-path`](https://www.w3.org/TR/motion-1/#motion-path-property)
- [`motion-offset`](https://www.w3.org/TR/motion-1/#motion-offset)
- [`motion-rotation`](https://www.w3.org/TR/motion-1/#motion-rotation)
- And the shorthand, [`motion`](https://www.w3.org/TR/motion-1/#motion-shorthand).

As put by the [working draft page](https://www.w3.org/TR/motion-1/):

> This is a draft document and may be updated, replaced or obsoleted by other documents at any time. It is inappropriate to cite this document as other than work in progress.

In fact, there is a [*new draft*](https://www.w3.org/TR/motion-1/) of the working draft page, which changes all the properties, as well as adding some new ones:

- [`offset-path`](https://drafts.fxtf.org/motion-1/#propdef-offset-path)
- [`offset-distance`](https://drafts.fxtf.org/motion-1/#offset-distance-property)
- [`offset-position`](https://drafts.fxtf.org/motion-1/#offset-position-property)
- [`offset-anchor`](https://drafts.fxtf.org/motion-1/#offset-anchor-property)
- [`offset-rotate`](https://drafts.fxtf.org/motion-1/#offset-rotate-property)
- And the [`offset`](https://drafts.fxtf.org/motion-1/#offset-shorthand) shorthand.

This module, including the `path()` function, is still far, far away from any wide use, and not just because of it's [horrible browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=pathZ).

#### The module is still a draft, an experimental part of CSS.

It's so experimental that all of the properties are being renamed/remade in the newest draft. Because of this, the syntax could change, properties could be renamed/added/removed again, or the entire module could be dropped (Not that likely, but it could happen).

This is the reason you've had such a hard time finding any information about this module, because it simply isn't in a state to be used now.

Play around with it in chrome, sure. Use it for something where you actually want it to continue working, no.

#### References/helpful links:

- https://drafts.fxtf.org/motion-1/
- http://codepen.io/danwilson/post/css-motion-paths
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1186329
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/motion-path
- https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/css-motion-path/index.html
- http://status.modern.ie/cssmotionpath
- http://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6190642178818048
- https://www.w3.org/TR/motion-1/
- http://caniuse.com/#search=path